# Extracting Data from Asynchronous Function for UITable Return

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have a function called gatherData, which iterates through directories and data on a Firebase database. Because it uses asynchronous functions, I returning the data wasn't an apparent option. I used other solutions from previous problems to determine I needed a callback system. This appeared to work, however, I needed to return the array's length for a UITableView's number of rows, which needs to be returned. This caused problems once again with the async funcs. Please look at the code bellow at let me know if there are any alternate methods which would work or if anyone needs clarification.

Function to gather data:

```swift
func gatherData(following: Array<String>, completionHandler: @escaping (_ results: NSArray) -> ()) {
    var returnData: Array<Any> = []
    for follow in following {
        let refr = Database.database().reference(withPath: "/users/\(follow)/")
        refr.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let values = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            let postID = values["currentPostNumber"] as! Int
            var count: Int = 0
            if (postID > 1) {
                count = postID - 1
            }
            for index in 0...count {
                let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "/posts/\(follow)/\(index)/")
                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                    let captions = value["caption"] as! String
                    let pathToUserImg = value["userImg"] as! String
                    let refre = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "\(pathToUserImg)")
                    refre.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!) as Any
                        let insertIntoArray = [index, captions, image]
                        returnData.append(insertIntoArray)
                        if (index == count) {
                            completionHandler(returnData as NSArray)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

tableView:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare an array to store API's `dataArray` say,

```
var dataArray = [Any]()
```

You should never call API in `UITableView's datasource` method like this. Make a function say,

```
func getDataFromAPI() {
   //Call your api function here
   gatherData(following: [""]) { results in 
       self.dataArray = results
       self.yourTableView.reload() //Then reload your tableView
   }
}
```

And finally modify you `datasource` method's body like this :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,...) -> Int {
   return dataArray.count
}
```

And use `dataArray` to populate data in your controller.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for the help. I had not tried reloading the table view.

Answer (score 1):

Return value inside `numberOfRowsInSection` with completion block is not possible.

You need to call API first in `viewDidLoad`. After calling API successfully you need to reload data. Please refer below code.

```
   gatherData(following: [""]) { results in 
       self.aryResult = results
       self.tableView.reload()
   }
```

Now, You just need to return `self.aryResult.count` inside your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.